# can not see project class after clone

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-clone, netbeans-plugins

I'm beginner at git on netbeans.well,when I'm clone a repository from github show me create netbeans project instead of open netbeans project and after select that doesn't show any class in project tab.
[image: here is picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the exact nature of the project (java?) and its folder structure.

See "[Step by step directions for NetBeans IDE:](http://wpollock.com/AJava/Proj-B-Git.htm) " by [Wayne Pollock](http://wpollock.com/)

> - Click `Next` to create a clone of the repo (under the NetBeans projects folder).  This should also scan for projects.
>
> Not finding any NetBeans project files, the “`Create project`” wizard should launch automatically.
>   It may show a popup window instead, with “`Do you want to create an IDE project from the cloned sources?`”. If so, proceed by clicking the `Create Project...` button.)
>   Use “`Java Project with existing sources`”, and click `Next`.
>
> - Pick some project name (e.g., “`Proj2`”), and hit Next.
> - Click the “`Add Folder`” button (for the “`Source Package Folders`” section), and select the “`src`” project folder.  Click `Next`.
> - Make sure `mypkg/Main.java` shows in the list of included files.
>     Then click the `Finish` button.
>
> **If you only see “`Main.java`” and not “`mypkg/Main.java`”, then you didn't have the correct folder selected in the previous step.
>
>   In this case, hit the “`Back`” button, click on the folder to select it, and hit the “`Remove`” button.
>
>   Now click the “`Add folder...`” button and try again.**
>
> That's it!  You should now have a local repo, and a NetBeans project linked with it.